# How should interface implementations handle unexpected internal exceptions of types callers might expect?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exception, interface

If a class implements an interface, how should it handle the situations where either

1. In the execution of a method or property, an internal error occurs which is of a type which a caller might reasonably be expecting to handle, but which a caller perhaps should not.  For example, IDictionary.Add does something internally which yields an ArgumentException under circumstances which would imply that the dictionary is corrupt, but would not imply anything bad about the rest of the system?  Or they imply that something is corrupted beyond the dictionary?  A caller may be expecting to catch and handle the fact that a duplicate key exists in the dictionary, since in some cases the exception may be Vexing (e.g. the same code may be used for a Dictionary that's not accessed by other threads and for a ConcurrentDictionary which is, and the semantics would be workable if an attempt to add a duplicate record caused a clean failure).  Letting an ArgumentException percolate would lead a caller to believe that the dictionary is in the same state as if the add never occurred, which could be dangerous, but throwing some other exception type would seem confusing.

   In the execution of a method or property, an exception occurs which the caller maybe should or shouldn't handle, and the definition of the interface doesn't provide any hint that any even-remotely-related exception might occur.  For example, suppose something goes wrong in the evaluation of IEnumerator, either implying (1) the enumerator got corrupted (possibly by unexpected action on another thread) but retrying the enumeration might succeed; (2) the enumerable object itself is probably corrupted or unusable, but everything else in the system is probably okay (e.g. a lazily-evaluated file parsing routine hit an invalid record); (3) something beyond the enumerable object has been corrupted.  IEnumerable only has one defined exception it can throw, but a caller may want to vary its action based upon the 'severity' of the exception.

If I had my druthers, the system would define some types like RetryableFailureException, CleanFailureException, ObjectCorruptFailureException, and most interfaces would be allowed to throw those or derivatives thereof.  Since that's not the case, how should one properly handle interfaces, either from the view of the interface or the caller?

BTW, one pattern I've not seen implemented, but would seem useful, would be for methods to accept a delegate parameter to be executed in case the method fails in a way that would cause a "try" method to return false.  Such a delegate, supplied by the caller, could then not only throw an exception which the recipient would know to look for, but could also set a flag that was otherwise available only to the caller.  The caller could thus know that the exception being caught was indeed the one expected.

Answer (score 0):

An Interface's job is to define the members (and their signatures) that a class must have, not how they should be implemented.  Therefore I would say let the exception bubble up the stack.  If you really want to define the contract and control some of the implementation (such as error handling) then you should make a base class (I would lean towards a MustInherit/Abstract class in this situation) with MustOverride Methods that the base class calls from its methods (in your situation in a Try Catch so you can do your special error handling).

Comment: An interface doesn't define how the members should be implemented, but in practical terms, interfaces are supposed to be associated with behaviors described in their documentation.  If something implements IList<Integer>, it's supposed to behave like an addressable collection.  Calling Add(5) should put another item in the collection with value 5; it shouldn't e.g. increase the value of all items in the collection by 5.  It would seem that the exceptions that may be thrown by an interface method should be considered part of its behavior.

Comment: I think what @NoAlias is trying to say is: An interface is a way to define the required structure of an object, while a base class is how you would code those requirements.  So you name the function in the interface, and then code it's most basic or required processes within the base class.  Yes, you can have an "error" struct within the interface, but the actual error handling and population of the struct should be coded in the base class.

Comment: MSDN, (remarks section): An interface defines a set of members, such as properties and procedures, that classes and structures can implement. The interface defines only the signatures of the members and not their internal workings.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9xt0sdd.aspx

Comment: "interfaces are supposed to be associated with behaviors described in their documentation" - YES, but think of all the crappy implementations of Google or Twitter's Public Interfaces that exist out there.  Thankfully, they don't over complicate their interfaces to compensate for edge case errors or bad programming though.  I think you're trying to extend the inteded functionality of an Interface too much and will only complicate things.  Make a base class or leave it up to the consumers of the interface to deal with is what I recommend.